# How share files from Vista to Mac with ethernet?

Tags: ethernet

I tried reading several guides, but none of them work.

I have a Vista without wireless access. I want to transfer files to a Mac using ethernet. How can I do this?

The Mac can share to XP fine, and the Vista can share to XP (both using direct connection with an ethernet cable), but I can't get the Vista to share with Mac.

If I try to connect using Mac's Connect to Server, it returns an error.

I looked up both the Vista name and the Ipv address. I went to Go>Connect to Server on Mac, then entered smb://(Vista name). It loaded a dialog to ask me to enter a username/password. Nothing I enter works. I've tried changing the username to Vista's, to Mac's; entering the passwords for both; and I've tried entering smb://(ipv address).

Comment: We can't see over your shoulder, please explain exactly what you have done & what error you got.

Comment: I looked up both the Vista name and the Ipv6 address. I went to Go>Connect to Server on Mac, then entered smb://(Vista name). It loaded a dialog to ask me to enter a username/password. Nothing I enter works. I've tried changing the username to Vista's, to Mac's; entering the passwords for both; and I've tried entering smb://(ipv4 address).

Comment: The error is that it can't connect. See an administrator.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Lets start with the basics...How are you connecting them to Ethernet? Are you using a router or switch? Direct to each other? Please [edit] to add your details.

Comment: Direct to each other, yes. The puzzling thing is that Mac>XP and XP>Vista works, but Mac>Vista doesn't.